# PHP/MySQL - Best use and practice of escaping strings

Tags: mysql, string, escaping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

What is the best way to escape strings when making a query?
mysql_real_escape_string() seems good but I do not exactly know how to use it in properly.

Does this code do the job properly?

```
<?php
   /* Let's say that the user types "'#""#''"\{(})#&/\€ in a textfield */
   $newStr = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
   $query = "INSERT INTO table username VALUES ($str)";
   mysql_query($query);
?>
```

EDIT:

Now I have this code:

```
      $email = $_POST['email'];
    $displayName = $_POST['displayName'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass1'];

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);
    $displayName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $displayName);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $pass);

    $insert = "INSERT INTO profiles (email, displayName, password)
    VALUES ('$email', '$displayName', md5('$pass'))";
    mysqli_query($link, $insert)
    or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

But I get this error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*!"#!#^!"#!"*#!"#^'''''' at line 1

If the user enters:
'**!"#!#^!"#!"*#!"#^''''

Comment: `mysql_*` funtions are about to be deprecated. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way is not to escape the string at all, but instead use a parameterized query, which does it for you behind the scenes.

Comment: And how do you make a parameterized query?

Comment: Parameterized query using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Look at the connections section of the link Lion posted.

Answer (score 6):

Using `mysql_real_escape_string` like that will work, but you need to:

- Add quotes around the value.
- Use the result `$newStr`, not the original value `$str`.
- Change the tablename to a name that isn't a reserved keyword.
- Add parentheses around the column list.

Try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO yourtable (username) VALUES ('$newStr')";
```

I also suggest that you check the result of `mysql_query($query)` and if there is an error, you can examine the error message:

```
if (!mysql_query($query))
{
    trigger_error(mysql_error());
}
```

You should also consider using one of the newer interfaces to MySQL. The old `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) and should not be used in new code.

Comment: `table` was actually ok as it represents the table name... (`username` is the field name)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've added that to the list of things that need to be fixed in that line of code.

Comment: Nice work, can't give you another +1 :)

Comment: Check edited first post.